# Summing a count of a value in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure if I am doing this SQL in the best way. So hoping for any advice. I am using this query.

```
SELECT
    Part_No,
    Serial_No,
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(Grade_Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MAX(Grade_Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No)
        WHEN MIN(Grade_Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MAX(Grade_Date) > @EndDate THEN COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No)
    END AS 'Incoming_Freq',
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(Grade_Date) < @StartDate THEN COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No)
    END AS 'Opening_Freq'
FROM Inventory
WHERE
    Regrade = 1
GROUP BY
    Part_No,
    Serial_No
```

[image]

And it gives me output as per the following.
Which is fine. But I need it to sum those frequencies per part. But no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to do it.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show input plus expected output of that input?

Comment: Do you mean like using `over()` with `count()`? e.g. `count(distinct serial_no) over (partition by part_no)`?

Comment: Maybe I havn't used the over or partition before?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at things, I think we may need a sample of data and how it should be returned, or a description of what it is you have and want. I suspect that this is still incorrect, but it seems to implement your original version correctly (with my addition after the comment).

```
SELECT
    Part_No,
    Serial_No,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Min_Grade_Date >= @StartDate 
                AND Max_Grade_Date >= @StartDate 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END 
        ) As Incoming_Freq,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MAX_Grade_Date < @StartDate 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
        ) AS Opening_Freq,
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- I added this to catch all the other records that seem to be being missed
    -- This is the case when the Max_Grade_Date >= @StartDate, but the 
    -- Min_Grade_Date is < @StartDate. It looks like those accidentally get
    -- ignored in your version and my earlier version.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Max_Grade_Date >= @StartDate AND Min_Grade_Date < @StartDate
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
        ) AS Unknown_Freq
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        Part_No,
        Serial_No,
        MIN(Grade_Date) as Min_Grade_Date,
        Max(Grade_Date) as Max_Grade_Date
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE
        Regrade = 1
    GROUP BY
        Part_No,
        Serial_No
    HAVING Max(Grade_Date) <= @EndDate
    ) as Source
GROUP BY Part_No,
    Serial_no
```

----------------- Original Entry below --------------------------
I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    Part_No,
    Serial_No,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MIN(Grade_Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
                AND MAX(Grade_Date) > @StartDate 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END 
        ) As Incoming_Freq,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(Grade_Date) < @StartDate 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
        ) AS Opening_Freq
FROM Inventory
WHERE
    Regrade = 1
GROUP BY
    Part_No,
    Serial_No
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to this but get the error - Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Oh bother. I really dislike that specific error. The workaround for that is to make the query multi-tiered,,,, like I will in after I edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Part_No
        , Serial_No
        , MAX(Grade_Date) AS MaxDate
        , MIN(Grade_Date) AS MinDate
        , COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No) AS Number_Serial_No
    FROM
        Inventory
    WHERE
        Regrade = 1
    GROUP BY
        Part_No
        , Serial_No
)
SELECT
    Part_No
    , SUM ( CASE
        WHEN MinDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND MaxDate >= @StartDate THEN Number_Serial_No
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Sum_Incoming_Freq
    , SUM (CASE
        WHEN MaxDate < @StartDate THEN Number_Serial_No
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Sum_Opening_Freq
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    Part_No;
```

Comment: This is close to what I want but it counts each serial twice.

Comment: @Danrex Then, can you provide clear examples of what you want? I did not see that in your question.